# ReplaceAll in Json

Tags: json, groovy

I'm writting a Groovy script (Groovy 2.4.6)

A JsonBuilder object contains :

```
 "GestionAffaire": [
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ModifierSaisine",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_DetaillerProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ControlerReservationPossible",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_RechercherSaisine",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_CloturerAffaireSurMesure",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_AjouterNoteProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ListerNoteProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ConsulterSuiviCommAvv",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_RechercherProjetCollectif",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_CREASM_1",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectifValide",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_SupprimerProjetCollectif",
    "SoapHttpDelivery_SUB_EPAVVI_1",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ReserverEntreprise",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_AnnulerContractualisationProjetCollectif",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_MAJPSM_3",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_MAJPSM_2",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectifEtude",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_CPSM_2",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ContractualiserProjetCollectif"
 ],
```

I want each line of GestionAffaire to look like **"SAM_GestionAffaire_ModifierSaisine" : "1"**

So I tried the following with the parsed Json:
     jsonString.replaceAll("\"," , "\": \"1\"," )

But nothing in the String is changing, I also tried basic expressions but the String remains unchanged.

Do you have any idea / alternative ?

Regards

Thomas

Comment: Make an mcve, something that we can run and duplicate your results. Also, you don't need to use doublequotes to demarcate your strings (passed to replaceAll) if you're not interpolating. Using slashy strings or just singlequotes would be more legible here, no escape chars required.

Answer (score 0):

SO assuming you have the data in a Map (I assume you had it in a map to pass it to a _JsonBuilder object?)

```
def map = [GestionAffaire:[
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ModifierSaisine",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_DetaillerProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ControlerReservationPossible",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_RechercherSaisine",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_CloturerAffaireSurMesure",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_AjouterNoteProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ListerNoteProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ConsulterSuiviCommAvv",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_RechercherProjetCollectif",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_CREASM_1",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectifValide",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectif",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_SupprimerProjetCollectif",
    "SoapHttpDelivery_SUB_EPAVVI_1",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ReserverEntreprise",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_AnnulerContractualisationProjetCollectif",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_MAJPSM_3",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_MAJPSM_2",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectifEtude",
    "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_CPSM_2",
    "SAM_GestionAffaire_ContractualiserProjetCollectif"
]]
```

Then you can just change the map:

```
map.GestionAffaire = map.GestionAffaire.collectEntries { [it, '1'] }
```

so that it is like you want:

```
assert map == [GestionAffaire:[
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_ModifierSaisine": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_DetaillerProjetCollectif": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_ControlerReservationPossible": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_RechercherSaisine": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_CloturerAffaireSurMesure": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_AjouterNoteProjetCollectif": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_ListerNoteProjetCollectif": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_ConsulterSuiviCommAvv": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_RechercherProjetCollectif": '1',
        "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_CREASM_1": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectifValide": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectif": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_SupprimerProjetCollectif": '1',
        "SoapHttpDelivery_SUB_EPAVVI_1": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_ReserverEntreprise": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_AnnulerContractualisationProjetCollectif": '1',
        "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_MAJPSM_3": '1',
        "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_MAJPSM_2": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_EnregistrerProjetCollectifEtude": '1',
        "Enrichment_PUB_PUB_CPSM_2": '1',
        "SAM_GestionAffaire_ContractualiserProjetCollectif": '1'
    ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking this?

The result of this call IS a string, it will not modify the original

```
def newString = jsonString.replaceAll( ... )
```